# Display the Object with the most equal entries

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

Hi I want to display the country(Land in german) which haves the most museums.

My table looks like:

```
+-----------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| MuseumsNR | Name                 | Stadt             | Land                     | Hauptstadt    |
+-----------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
|         1 | Museum of Modern Art | New York          | United States of America | Washington DC |
|         2 | Kunstmuseum          | Bern              | Schweiz                  | Bern          |
|         3 | Musée Picasso        | Paris             | Frankreich               | Paris         |
|         4 | Städel               | Frankfurt am Main | Deutschland              | Berlin        |
|         5 | Museum Ludwig        | Köln              | Deutschland              | Berlin        |
+-----------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

So my desired output should be:

```
+--------------------------+------+
| Land                     |Anzahl|
+--------------------------+------+
| Deutschland              |    2 |
+--------------------------+------+
```

This is what i´ve tried:

```
SELECT Land, COUNT(Name) Name from  Museum order by Name desc;
```

THe Output:

```
+--------------------------+------+
| Land                     | Name |
+--------------------------+------+
| United States of America |    5 |
+--------------------------+------+
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Land, count(*) as Anzahl 
    FROM yourTable 
    GROUP BY Land 
    ORDER BY Anzahl 
    DESC LIMIT 1;`
```

Only tested in PostgreSQL, but should be close enough in MySQL.